# Stuck when trying to install Ubuntu alongside windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, usb

So i am trying to dual boot Ubuntu to my system. I download the latest desktop version, use rufus to get it on a usb and choose to boot from the usb in bios. The ubuntu menu appears and when i choose "install ubuntu" the screens go black and after a bit they go sleep mode. The pc is still running but is unresponsive. I tried with another usb aswell as another version of the os and nothing changed. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the **nomodeset** option in the bottom right corner of the menu screen then try installing Ubuntu again (in the case of GUI installer)

However if  grub like installer, highlight "install Ubuntu" and press TAB but don't press enter just yet add **nomodeset** right after where it says `splash` then resume the installation.

Comment: Uhm could you elaborate? I dont see that option in the Ubuntu menu. Is it somewhere in the BIOS?

Comment: @Lampros K. Are you getting a GUI  or grub like installation screen?