# Trouble Installing Ubuntu In Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, secure-boot

I've had my computer for over a year now, and since the day I've bought him I've been trying to install Ubuntu (or another Linux partition) in dual boot, and I was never able to.
Basically, everytime I'm in the installion process, my computer either freezes midway or doesn't let me choose which option I want.
This has happened with several partitions, and I've disabled secure boot everytime I tried to install it.
Some people at my university say it has to do with my graphics card, but I don't really know why this happens. I also have a friend with the same pc model as me, and he can't install linux in dual boot aswell.
Does anyone know what can be causing this and how to solve it?

Comment: What computer and graphics card? Nvidia?

Comment: possible duplicate of this question http://askubuntu.com/a/894691/479889

Comment: my computer is an asus k550j and my graphics card is a nvidia ge force gtx 950m

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `nomodeset` when launching the Live CD/USB. See [the following answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898101/repeated-flickering-on-fresh-ubuntu-16-install-attempt/898175#898175).